# Ubuntu 12.04 application shortcut on top panel

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

[image: **enter image description here**]

How to make application shortcuts in Ubuntu top panel? Which script need to edit? I don't like to drag and drop. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 with  gnome-classic session.

Answer (score 2):

You are logged into Gnome-Classic session with compiz enabled "Gnome-Classic (with effects)". Compiz block those customization.

### Drag and drop

1. First Logout from this session.
2. Log into "Gnome-Classic (without effects)" session
3. Then choose a menu item, Press and hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and drag the icon at the top panel.

You can now Logout and Login again to the "Gnome-Classic (with effect)" session.

### Without drag and drop

1. Login to "Gnome-Classic (No effect)" session
2. Press and Hold the <kbd>Alt</kbd>
3. While holding Alt key, right click on the top panel
4. Select "Add to panel"
5. Choose "Application launcher"
6. Click on the "Forward" button at the bottom.
7. Select the desired application icon from the list. You can add a complete category such as "Sound & Video" to the panel!
8. Click "Add" button or double click the Application entry.

You're done. Now login again to Gnome-Classic (with effect) session.

If you want to remove any icon, Login back to the "gnome-classic (No effect" session and remove the icon by  holding the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key , right click and select "Remove from panel".